# Module not found in react for render image from api

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, api

I currently creating a react app of e-commerce, I am stuck with a feature where when the product clicks and redirects to the product details page, I successfully can get the product image and the details using props but can't get the product image. The product image needs a call from an API. So I try to direct call from the src. But I getting the error of the Module not being found. Plz, help me with this.

Getting an error in the code in this line where I try to call the API directly tp src.
[image]

This is the error I'm getting
[image]

```html
// carousel items
  const carouselItems = [
    {
      
      src: require(`/api/v1/ProductFile/${encodeURIComponent(
                        data.data.ID
                      )}/Product/${encodeURIComponent(
                        data.data.ProductImages[0]
                      )}`),
      altText: "Somewhere",
      caption: "Somewhere",
    },
    {
      src: require("assets/img/megan-product-2.jpg"),
      altText: "Somewhere else",
      caption: "Somewhere else",
    },
    {
      src: require("assets/img/megan-product-3.jpg"),
      altText: "Here it is",
      caption: "Here it is",
    },
    {
      src: require("assets/img/megan-product-4.jpg"),
      altText: "Here it is",
      caption: "Here it is",
    },
  ];
  
   <div>
      <Row>
        <Col key={data.data.ID} md="7" sm="6">
          <div className="ml-auto mr-auto" id="carousel">
            <Card className="page-carousel">
              <Carousel
                activeIndex={activeIndex}
                next={next}
                previous={previous}
              >
                <CarouselIndicators
                  items={carouselItems}
                  activeIndex={activeIndex}
                  onClickHandler={goToIndex}
                />
                {carouselItems.map((item) => (
                  <CarouselItem
                    onExiting={onExiting}
                    onExited={onExited}
                    key={item.src}
                  >
                    <img src={item.src} alt={data.data.Name} />
                    <CarouselCaption captionHeader={data.data.Name} />
                  </CarouselItem>
                ))}
               
               
              </Carousel>
            </Card>
          </div>
          {/* end carousel */}
        </Col>
        
      </Row>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to call the image API which included the productID and imageID , not from folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, I have solved it by just remove the require word.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `require()` wrapping the API URL.

---

The error is telling you that the file path does not exist.

Each item in the `Carousel` uses an `<img>` that takes an `src` attribute. To use an API endpoint/URL for the `src`, it should be passed directly as a string without using `require`.